# How to get rid of wait time when a key is kept pressed in handling keyboard events in GLUT?

Tags: c, opengl, glut, keyboard-events

I have created a game using openGL in C. The game features a slider that can be moved left or right using arrow keys. Code is as given below (for handling keyboard events).

When I press any key(left or right) the slider moves by one unit then waits for a certain time and then keeps continuously moving until I release the key.

It is natural as computer waits for us to release key so as to verify whether we want multiple key stroke to be fed as input or we were just slow to release the key.
But this feature comes in the way of making slider responsive enough.

Is there any way to get rid of this? I have seen games in javascript where this problem doesn't arise.
Thanks!!

```
void specialKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        sliderX -= 10;
        if (sliderX < sliderXMin)
            sliderX = sliderXMin;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        sliderX += 10;
        if (sliderX > sliderXMax)
            sliderX = sliderXMax;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        xSpeed *= 1.05;
        ySpeed *= 1.05;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        xSpeed *= 0.95;
        ySpeed *= 0.95;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL does not deal with user input. In your case you're using GLUT, which is not part of OpenGL and this is doing the user input stuff for you.

With GLUT what you want to do is difficult to achieve, because the keyboard callback is just called for character code input. What you want is getting events if a key is pressed and later depressed to set a flag, which you use to update the position in a timed loop.

Fortunately GLUT is not the only framework around. There are many others, better suited for the development of games, because of their far finer grained user input control. Well suited for games are GLFW, SDL-2 and SFML. I suggest you use one of those.

Comment: Below link says that gl, glu and glut are part of openGL
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/CG_Introduction.html#zz-2.

Comment: @Nirmal: The link you posted is just some tutorial on some schools website. Hardly an authorative source. The *only* relevant document that describes what is part of OpenGL is the *OpenGL specification*: https://www.opengl.org/registry/#apispecs – GLU and GLUT are certainly part of the OpenGL ecosystem but they **are not** part of OpenGL. Also GLU and GLUT are terribly outdated. GLU relies on deprecated OpenGL functionality that has been *removed* from OpenGL-3 onward. The original GLUT has not even been maintained in this century.

Comment: I guess I will shift my code to GLFW most probably.
Thank you!